# C: Algorithm to cut rectangle into squares

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

I tried doing this problem set from Codewars and ran my code through the compiler. It indicated a segmentation fault but I don't know where I'm going wrong. The problem set is as follows:

The drawing below gives an idea of how to cut a given "true" rectangle into squares ("true" rectangle meaning that the two dimensions are different).

[image: [Click here for picture of the drawing]]

Can you translate this drawing into an algorithm?

You will be given two dimensions - a positive integer length (parameter named lng)
a positive integer width (parameter named wdth).
You will return an array.

My code is as follows:

```
typedef struct Data Data;
struct Data {
     int *array;
     int sz;
};

Data* sqInRect(int lng, int wdth) {
  Data* ptr = (Data*) malloc(sizeof(Data));
  // if square length == square width
  if(lng == wdth){
    ptr->array = NULL;
    ptr->sz = 0;
    return 1;
  }
  //initialise variables
  int rmdLength,rmdWidth,rmdSmallSquares,rmdLengthTimes,rmdWidthTimes,SIZE,temp=0;

  //assign length to temporary rmd variable
  rmdLength = lng;
  //calc how many squares of side *wdth* inside rect
  while((lng-wdth)>wdth){
    rmdLength -= wdth;
    rmdLengthTimes++;
  }
  rmdLength -= wdth;
  rmdLengthTimes++;
  //assign width to temporary rmdWidth variable
  rmdWidth = wdth;
  //calc how many squares of side *rmdWidth* inside rect (remaining area)
  while(rmdWidth>rmdLength){
    rmdWidth -= rmdLength;
    rmdWidthTimes++;
  }
  rmdWidth -= rmdLength;
  rmdWidthTimes++;
  //calculate final number of remaining squares
  rmdSmallSquares = rmdLength/rmdWidth;
  //calculate SIZE
  SIZE = rmdLengthTimes + rmdWidthTimes + rmdSmallSquares;
  //declaration of array
  int arr[SIZE];
  //for loop to put square values in array
  temp = rmdLengthTimes + rmdWidthTimes;
  for(int i=0;i<rmdLengthTimes;i++){
    arr[i] = wdth;
  }
  for(int j=rmdLengthTimes;j<temp;j++){
    arr[j] = rmdLength;
  }
  for(int k=temp;k<SIZE;k++){
    arr[k]= rmdWidth;
  }
  //get Data* ptr to store array AND size of that array
  ptr->array = arr;
  ptr->sz = SIZE;
  return ptr;
}
```

I'd appreciate it if someone could clarify with me over where I went wrong. I have been stuck on this problem for way too long. Thank you.

Comment: For segmentation faults it would always be a good start to run your code in a debugger. it will show you were the problem occurs.

Comment: What is your data structure supposed to contain? You only fill it with 3 different values.

Comment: Not causing a SEGFAULT, bit an endless loop: `while((lng-wdth)>wdth){rmdLength -= wdth; rmdLengthTimes++;}`. You never change the variables in loop condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of variables uninitialized in the following line:

```
  int rmdLength,rmdWidth,rmdSmallSquares,rmdLengthTimes,rmdWidthTimes,SIZE,temp=0;
```

**Note:** The above line **will not** initialize all the variables to `0`. It only initializes `temp` to `0`.

To initialize all the variables to `0`, you have to first declare them and then initialize them like this:

```
int rmdLength, rmdWidth, rmdSmallSquares, rmdLengthTimes, rmdWidthTimes, SIZE, temp;  
rmdLength = rmdWidth = rmdSmallSquares = rmdLengthTimes = rmdWidthTimes = SIZE = temp = 0;
```

The use of uninitialized variables results in undefined behaviour:
From the [online cpp reference on Uninitialized variables](https://en.cppreference.com/book/uninitialized):

> The value in an uninitialized variable can be anything – it is unpredictable, and may be different every time the program is run. **Reading the value of an uninitialized variable is undefined behaviour** – which is always a bad idea. It has to be initialized with a value before you can use it.

Also, in the following code, you are using the uninitialized variable `rmdLengthTimes` as a check to iterate through an array:

```
 for(int i=0;i<rmdLengthTimes;i++){
    arr[i] = wdth;
  }
```

This will result in accessing an out-of-bounds memory address which also is an undefined behaviour:

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior):

> **The behavior of some programming languages—most famously C and C++—is undefined in some cases**. In the standards for these languages the semantics of certain operations is described as undefined. These cases typically represent unambiguous bugs in the code, **for example indexing an array outside of its bounds**.

So proper initialization of all variables before using them will resolve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out where I went wrong. I initialised the variables and ran the code through the compiler again, only for it to indicate that I am still accessing an out-of-bounds memory address in the array. Have I still not corrected something else?

Comment: Before accessing any variable through a pointer, it is good to check if the pointer is not NULL. In this case, check `ptr`.  Also print the value of SIZE to see if it is as expected. Use debugger if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing out of bound for `arr` array.

```
arr[i] = wdth;
```

Because you have not initialized below variables;

```
  int rmdLength,rmdWidth,rmdSmallSquares,rmdLengthTimes,rmdWidthTimes,SIZE,temp=0;
```

And using them as `index` for array will lead to undefined behavior.

```
  SIZE = rmdLengthTimes + rmdWidthTimes + rmdSmallSquares;

  for(int k=temp;k<SIZE;k++){
    arr[k]= rmdWidth;
  }
```

Initialize as below.

```
  int rmdLength=0,rmdWidth=0,rmdSmallSquares=0,rmdLengthTimes=0,rmdWidthTimes=0,SIZE=0,temp=0;
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out where I went wrong. I initialised the variables and ran the code through the compiler again, only for it to indicate that I am still accessing an out-of-bounds memory address in the array. Have I still not corrected something else?